# How can I handle divergence failure manually when using optimize.newton in SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, convergence

I'm using newton optimize from SciPy to solve an equation and depending on the initial guess sometimes the solution does not converge and crashes.

```py
x = optimize.newton(fun,1/1000)
```

Would it be possible to print a message instead of the python crash message to say that convergence failed or retry optimization with different initial values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html):

> **disp: bool, optional**
>
> If True, raise a RuntimeError if the algorithm didn’t converge, with the error message containing the number of iterations and current function value. Otherwise the convergence status is recorded in a RootResults return object. Ignored if `x0` is not scalar. Note: this has little to do with displaying, however the `disp` keyword cannot be renamed for backwards compatibility.

You should set `disp` to `False`, because it is enabled by default:

```py
optimize.newton(fun, 1/1000, disp=False)
```

Your result and other information will be in a [`RootResults`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.RootResults.html#scipy.optimize.RootResults) object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. How do I raise a RuntimeError?

Comment: found a tutorial that helped with the RuntimeError. https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/exception-handling-python